# Pivot Table Independent Grand Total Row

Tags: qlikview

Is it possible to have a grand total row in a pivot table that is independent of selections? The table I am currently working with has region & branch dimensions and then several columns of data. I would like the company total to display at the bottom row regardless of what regions and/or branches are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dimensionality()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.0/Subsystems/Client/Content/ChartFunctions/InterRecordFunctions/dimensionality.htm?q=dimensionality) function.

As you can see from the picture below the rows have `Dimensionality() = 2` and the total row have `Dimensionality() = 0`

[image]

So in your case the expression will be something like this:

```
if(  Dimensionality() = 0, 
       sum( {< Region=, Branch= >} Value), 
       sum( Value ) 
)
```

(Don't forget to remove/disable the `Dimensionality()` column to test it. If not removed the chart will not behave as normal)

Using the above expression the total row will show the `sum( Value )` ignoring the selections in `Region` and `Branch` fields:

[image]

Also you can see that `Dimensionality()` is changing depends on the table aggregation. For example when collapse the `Region` the `Dimensionality()` function is returning 1 for the rows:

[image]

**No need to tell you that if you have decent amount of data such expressions will decrease the performance!**

*There is also and [SecondaryDimensionality()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.0/Subsystems/Client/Content/ChartFunctions/InterRecordFunctions/secondarydimensionality.htm) function which is basically the same as `Dimensionality()` but for the horizontal pivot dimensions.*

Comment: Thank-you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way of accomplishing this would be to have a straight table directly below your pivot table using set analysis to exclude selections.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I was hoping to avoid this because the positioning will be off when expanding/collapsing the pivot table

Comment: I see... I don't think you can get what you're after - by the nature of it if you are removing selections then your pivot table would always be fully expanded. There are more options surrounding totals on straight tables but I understand pivot tables to be a lot more locked down